# Rasa crashes when a message is sent

Tags: rasa

I have installed Rasa without any errors. When I run rasa shell the server is started and I am presented with the chatbot prompt. when I enter hi I get the following error:

```
Bot loaded. Type a message and press enter (use '/stop' to exit):
Your input ->  hi
Exception occurred while handling uri: 'http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook?stream=true&token='
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sanic\app.py", line 946, in handle_request
    request, request_name=name
TypeError: _run_request_middleware() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request_name'
Exception occurred in one of response middleware handlers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sanic\app.py", line 1017, in handle_request
    request, response, request_name=name
TypeError: _run_response_middleware() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request_name'
2020-01-04 11:29:30 ERROR    asyncio  - Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<configure_app.<locals>.run_cmdline_io() done, defined at g:\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\run.py:124> exception=ClientResponseError(RequestInfo(url=URL('http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook?stream=true&token='), method='POST', headers=<CIMultiDictProxy('Host': 'localhost:5005', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'User-Agent': 'Python/3.7 aiohttp/3.6.2', 'Content-Length': '38', 'Content-Type': 'application/json')>, real_url=URL('http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook?stream=true&token=')), (), status=500, message='Internal Server Error', headers=<CIMultiDictProxy('Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Keep-Alive': '5', 'Content-Length': '144', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8')>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\run.py", line 128, in run_cmdline_io
    server_url=constants.DEFAULT_SERVER_FORMAT.format("http", port)
  File "g:\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\channels\console.py", line 140, in record_messages
    async for response in bot_responses:
  File "g:\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\channels\console.py", line 104, in send_message_receive_stream
    async with session.post(url, json=payload, raise_for_status=True) as resp:
  File "g:\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "g:\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 588, in _request
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "g:\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 946, in raise_for_status
    headers=self.headers)
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 500, message='Internal Server Error', url=URL('http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook?stream=true&token=')
```

I have had no issues installing an since I am new to Rasa I am not sure what the problem is.

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your sanic version it may not match the requirements.
Has to be 19.9.0

Run this to install the right version:

> pip install sanic==19.9.0